# School tutorial advise please

Tags: java, string, boolean

One of my school tutorial requires us to create a coin tossing application.
Beginning of the question I already got confused.

It says:

A coin has an instance variable that indicates whether a result was heads or tails. What type should this instance variable be?

**So it should be boolean right? but how is it possible?**

The next bit says:

The constructor for a coin should initialise the face of the coin to heads. The constructor has no parameters.

The coin has two methods:

•   A method to return the result of the toss (i.e. returns the instance variable indicating heads or tails).
•   A method to toss the coin

Then next will be:

The method to toss the coin requires a random number, either 0 or 1.

We can get a random number using a method of the Math class. Math.random() returns a double value between 0 and 1. To convert this value to an integer, either 0 or 1, the following code is used

int num = (int)(Math.random() *2); //returns an integer

Comment: well.. there are only 2 probabilities for a coin.. Now, lets see, which data type has only 2 states?

Comment: boolean heads = true?

Comment: It can be enum too.

Comment: boolean and just in the comments put True = Heads... or you can go with enums if you want it more 'pretty'

Comment: I agree, enum would be good. But seeing that this is a tutorial, I would go with boolean first since it is either true or false. I guess conventionally, head would be true whereas tails would be false.

Comment: @shekharsuman - if it could be an `Enum`, it could also be `null`. A coin can *never* have an *unknown* state

Comment: @TheLostMind It could if you haven't flipped it yet.

Comment: @TheLostMind-yeah if you haven't flipped it then!

Comment: @Michelle - And what happens after flipping?. You are saying that it could *still be null*. Is it possible?. Unless you are considering that it could also stand on its perimeter.. :P

Comment: Why are we telling a beginning to over complicate things when a simple boolean works perfectly fine? KISS.

Comment: @TheLostMind Any object could always be null, whether or not it makes logical sense. Sure, the program could leave it null instead of setting it after flipping, but that's faulty logic, not a faulty representation. Alternatively, if you might want to know if the coin hasn't been flipped, a boolean _is_ a faulty representation, because it can't handle a third state.

Comment: @Michelle- a `boolean` can never be `null`. Plus, as for the initial state, we could assume it to be *heads* (which we are going to ignore/overwrite anyways once the coin is tossed)

Comment: @TheLostMind A `boolean` isn't an _object_, so what's your point? Again, it can't differentiate between flipped-and-landed-heads and not-flipped, which may be a faulty model depending on use case.

Comment: @Michelle - He could have a `Coin` class with `boolean` as a field. Anyways, lets not drag this thing . :)

Comment: Very correct logic @Michelle,I'm with you.This `enum` model is very close to the real world `coin-tossing problem`,including nulls too!

Comment: I would go with enum also... It is more future proof. What if tomorrow you decide to throw dice instead of a coin?!?

Answer (score 1):

Well,if you have studied deeply,then you can apply `enum` here.

As, `enum CoinToss{heads,tails}`.

If you haven't studied this much,you can simply assign `boolean` to it.

Like,`boolean heads=true;`
     `boolean tails=false;`

Comment: oh we haven't reach enum that stage yet lol but i will go research about it as well thanks for the info bro.

Comment: how do i assign boolean to it like the one you talking about?

Comment: You can do `boolean toss=heads;` or `boolean toss=tails;` for your output as I have shown in the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Boolean is the correct form.

Remember as a programmer you are creating *representations* of the real world to try and solve problems efficiently and accurately.

You could just set it as strings "head" and "tails", but that would require a lot of resources for something that you just want to know if it is one of two states.

This particular example may seem trivial, but what if you had a million or a billion coins to keep track of?

Oh, and by the way, make sure to document which one is heads or tails. Usually heads' is true.

Comment: Indeed. So is true/false a representation of two sides of a coin? Which one is true and which one is false?

Comment: I'd name the variable based on which value is equivalent to true (e.g., call the variable `heads`). That is, you're not tracking which side landed up, but whether heads landed up (which is either true or false).

Comment: Gimby, that is up to you. This is what makes programming so much fun, it's a creative act that solves problem. Like I said in my comment, most people would think getting a heads would be a true, but you could make tail a true. Just make sure either way that you document what you choose so that future programmers can tell what you did.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it in this instance would be having the side of the coin facing up as an instance variable and then have constants to be able to refer to them by name.  For example:

```
public class Coin {
    public boolean side;
    public static final boolean HEADS = true;
    public static final boolean TAILS = false;
}
```

Like this, you can check to see if a Coin called quarter is heads by checking if `quarter.side == Coin.HEADS`.  Although this isn't the best performance (you're checking to see if something is equal to true), it makes the code more readable, which is especially important when you're starting out.
Also, for things like this but with more than 2 options, you would want to look into enums.

Answer (score -1):

```
//This enum represents the face of a coin
public enum CoinFace {
    HEADS,
    TAILS
}

public class Coin {

    //Default starting face for a coin
    private static CoinFace DEFAULT_FACE = CoinFace.TAILS;

    //The current face of the coin
    private CoinFace currentFace;

    public Coin() {
         currentFace = DEFAULT_FACE;
    }

    public void setFace(CoinFace face) {
         currentFace = face;
    }

    public CoinFace getFace() {
         return currentFace;
    }
}

public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

          //We create the coin instance
          Coin coinToToss = new Coin();

          //We will toss the coin 10 times
          for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
              System.out.println("Tossing coin...");
              coinToToss = tossCoin(coinToToss);
              System.out.println("Got " + coinToToss.getFace() + "!");
          }
     }

     private static Coin tossCoin(Coin coin) {

          //We will use the Random class for random results
          Random random = new Random();

          //We get a random enum value (coin face)
          int randomFace = random.nextInt(CoinFace.values().length);
          CoinFace tossedFace = CoinFace.values()[randomFace];

          coin.setFace(tossedFace);
          return coin;
     } 
}
```

Comment: Do you really think he asked for code??? I did not find it in the question!

Comment: He asked `how is it possible?`, by sowing a working code I'm therefore showing how it is actually possible

Comment: So this is where kids come to get there home work done ;)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple (and to me logical) way of setting up this variable. Your constructor:

```
public bool isHeads;
Constructor()
{ isHeads=true;}
```

Flip Coin Function:

```
void flipCoin()
{
 if((int)(Math.random() *2) ==1)
      isHeads = true;
 else
      isHeads = false;
}
```

Return result function:

```
bool getResult()
{ return isHeads;}
```